# Why does my jQuery UI Dialog lose the focus when it finishes the open effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor

I'm using jQuery UI Dialog for adding some news to my site. Every time I click `add news` button, the dialog should open with the text area. Actually, I'm using [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) replacing the `textarea` and it happens that I can't type inside the text editor due to `focus` issue (at least I think this is the problem).

Check it out. As just as I click `add news` button the dialog start to open with its effect. Notice the yellow bordered `textarea` meaning that it's focused (using Chrome) while it's appearing.
[image]
[Click to zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaLbA.jpg)

Notice then that when the dialog finishes appearing, it isn't focused anymore and I'm having trouble because of this

[image]
[Click to zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcK2D.jpg)

Also, check my code http://jsfiddle.net/pzHr2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a very well documented (tremendous understatement) feature that you can pass an object just as you can to the [`.show()` UI method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/#option-options) like this in your options:

```
show:{ effect: 'slide', complete: function() { $("textarea").first().focus(); }},
```

This runs the [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) when the animation completes, [you can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WksyV/).  If you're curious as to why this works, [you can take a look here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.effects.core.js#L437).

*Note:* this answer is for **jQuery UI 1.8.4+** (since you're using `.button()`), it won't work for 1.7.x users.

Comment: Thanks Nick, nice tip!!! 

Was just struggling with a similar issue (giving focus to the first input once a dialog opens with a show effect). I made a minor change to your code for my situation: 

`show: { effect: 'blind', complete: function () { $(this).find("input:first").focus(); } }`

Comment: I'm having the same problem loading my log in form into a modal dialog in MVC. The solution proposed here works fine in chrome and FF but convenient fails in IE9. Any ideas?